# When is the probability of A given B equal to probability of B given A?

Tags: probability

Can they ever equal each other?
If not, then is it because the denominator ($P(A)$ vs $P(B)$) is not the same?

I'm asking because in [Probability for the Enthusiastic Beginner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1523318678) (A wonderful book by the way), the author says they aren't equal ... In general.

Comment: For getting some intuition as to why they shouldn't even be expected to be the same, think of some example events. Should $P(\text{I dance} \mid \text{it rains})$ be the same as $P(\text{it rains} \mid \text{I dance})$?

Comment: Using the formula for the conditional probability you can see that they are equal iff $P(A) = P(B)$.

Comment: @Diamir Be careful with the iff assertion. If $A$ and $$B both have nonzero  probability and $P(A\cap B) = 0$, then $P(A\mid B) = P(B\mid A)$ without necessarily having $P(A) = P(B)$.

Comment: Flipping a fair coin twice: $P(H|T)=P(T|H)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $P(A),P(B),P(A\cap B)\neq 0$. Then
$$
P(A|B)=P(B|A) \Leftrightarrow \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)} \Leftrightarrow P(A)=P(B).
$$

Comment: Intriguingly, it doesn't matter if $A$ and $B$ are independent

Comment: $P(A \cap B) \neq 0$ is not needed here

Comment: @krirkrirk Well, for *this* deduction, it is. However, if $P(A\cap B)=0$ and $P(A)\ne 0$, $P(B)\ne 0$, then $P(A|B)=0=P(B|A)$ (so even if $P(A)\ne P(B)$, but they better be non-zero)

Answer (score 0):

They *can* be equal, but it would be a coincidence.  To see they are not equal in general, just think about how conceptually $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ are different kinds of probabilities.

To use a standard example: the probability that I test positive given that I have a certain disease (a measure of how accurate the test is in detecting the disease) is a different kind of probability from the probability that I have a certain disease, given that I test positive (which largely depends on the base prevalence of the disease: if the base rate is very low, there might be a good chances we are dealing with a false positive, no matter how accurate the test is)